# How to configure express router along with ES6?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, ecmascript-6

I have the following code for an router file in express.

```
import express from 'express';
import  _  from 'lodash';
import { Devices, OwlElecMonitors } from '../models/';

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/api/devices/:id',function (req, res) {
    console.log(req);                   
    Devices.getDevicesByUserId({ userId: req.params.id },function(err, resp) {
        res.send(resp);
    });
});

export default router;
```

and I am trying to import it into the main file using the following code

```
import api from './routes';
app.use('/api', api);
```

But the code returns a 404 error. Where am I going wrong ? What changes do I need to make for this to work ?

Comment: How are you running this? I can’t get ES6 modules to work even with the `--harmony_modules` flag.

Comment: Use typescript will help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your api is currently set to `/api/api/devices/:id`. 
Remove the `/api` from the router get definition:

```
router                  
    .get('/devices/:id',function (req, res) {
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Can also be resolved by skipping the mount param:

```
import api from './routes';
app.use(api);
```

Comment: That actually worked for me. Interesting, if I provide the mount param - it will break and return "Cannot GET /foo"... Why?

Comment: Ah, found it: 

// use the router and 401 anything falling through
app.use('/admin', router, function (req, res) {
  res.sendStatus(401)
})

At: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that all requests that go to "/api" are forwarded to the router. The router then only reacts to requests that contain an "/api" after the first "/api". Thus "/api" is required twice.

In the router, omit the first "api" segment;

```
import express from 'express';
import  _  from 'lodash';
import { Devices, OwlElecMonitors } from '../models/';

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/devices/:id',function (req, res) {
    console.log(req);                   
    Devices.getDevicesByUserId({ userId: req.params.id },function(err, resp) {
        res.send(resp);
    });
});
```

Or you leaf the router as it is and change the index.js to:

```
import api from './routes';
app.use('/', api);
```